# How to convert JSON into html table by selecting one JSON key as columns

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays, json

I have JSON format data something like this.

```
[
    {
        "user_id": "7",
        "field": "1",
        "value": "45"
    },
    {
        "user_id": "10",
        "field": "1",
        "value": "53"
    },
    {
        "user_id": "7",
        "field": "2",
        "value": "40"
    },
    {
        "user_id": "10",
        "field": "2",
        "value": "45"
    },
    {
        "user_id": "7",
        "field": "3",
        "value": "65"
    },
    {
        "user_id": "10",
        "field": "3",
        "value": "69"
    },
    {
        "user_id": "7",
        "field": "4",
        "value": "14"
    },
    {
        "user_id": "10",
        "field": "4",
        "value": "13"
    }
]
```

Now I want to convert it into Html table which will shows like this.

```
   user_id         1       2      3        4
   7              45      40     65       14
   10             53      45     69       13
```

My json data is in `$lika`
My code is:

```
    $arr = [];
    $id = "";
    foreach($lika as $value){
        if($id === $value['user_id']){
            echo "hfihf";
            array_push($v, $value['value']);
        }
        else{
            $v = [];
            array_push($v, $value['user_id']);
            array_push($v, $value['value']);
        }
        $arr[] = $v;
        $id = $value['user_id'];
    }
    print_r($arr);
```

Please help me to do this.

Comment: @sjaustirni. I have added the code that I have done.

Comment: What's the problem you are facing with the code?

Comment: I getting array with user_id and one value.

        [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 45
        )

Comment: Please can you show the specific piece of code that's not working.

Comment: where is js,html etc. that you have tried?

Comment: I tried using php foreach loop which I mentioned in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new array with the `user_id` as the array key and per  key create an array which holds the values.

To create your table you could loop that array (`$results` in the example) where the array key can be user for the column `user_id` and loop the array with the values to create the additional columns.

```
$results = [];
foreach ($arrays as $value) {
    $results[$value['user_id']][] = $value['value'];
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/7ZF5T)

Answer (score 0):

To keep field_id as key in resulting array, and with an HTML printed from the results, purely for demonstrational purposes :)

```
$arr = [];
foreach($data as $v){
     $arr[$v['user_id']][$v['field']] = $v['value'];
}
$i = 0;
echo '<table>';
foreach ($arr as $userId => $data) {
    if ($i === 0) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>user-id</td>';
        foreach (array_keys($data) as $field) {
            echo "<td>$field</td>";
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td>$userId</td>";
    foreach ($data as $field => $value) {
        echo "<td>$value</td>";
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    $i++;
}
echo '</table>';
```